# Laravel - Difference between @yield and @section?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

From the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates), you can include 'sections' inside layouts using two methods:

```
<html>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Since `@yield` can also pass in some default content using `@yield('section', 'Default Content')`, is `@yield` just a shorthand for a `@section` that does not use `@parent`?

```
@section
    <!-- Nothing here -->
@show
```

What other differences are there?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This line clears out the confusion: "Note that views which extend a Blade layout simply override sections from the layout. Content of the layout can be included in a child view using the `@parent` directive in a section".

So, if you already have a `@section` defined in the master layout, it will be overriden unless you specify `@parent` inside the child layout's `@section`.

But for `@yield`, it always gets the section from the child layout. That means it always overrides the `@yield` part, even if it has a default defined as `@yield('section', 'Default Content')` .

I hope that clears your confusion. Let me know if you have more questions. Thanks

Comment: So to nail this home - `@yield` is just a shorthand for a `@section` that do not use @parent? Correct?

Comment: Yes you can put it that way. `@yield` is always used to get content from a child page unto a master page.  So when the Laravel executes your blade file, it first checks if you have extended a master layout, if you have extended one, then it shifts to the master layout and starts getting the `@sections` that you have overridden and the main content i.e the `@yield` from the child layout. And of course, finally, it parses the blade format to raw php and gives the output in html/css/js .

Comment: I still don't get it.

Comment: @pvaitonis , which part are you still confused with? Let me know. Thanks

Comment: About difference between `@include` and `@yield`.

Comment: @pvaitonis `@include` is similar to php's include() function, but it still can have `@section`s inside it, if it has .blade extension and it will work out the exact same way as a child layout.  `@yield` only gets the appropriate `@section` from the child layout.

Comment: You should also discuss the use of `@stack()` and `@push()`. What is the difference between `@yield()` and `@stack()`?

Answer (score 60):

**Short Answer**: Always use `@yield` unless you want to do something more complicated then providing a default `string`.

---

**Long Answer**:
Both **@yield** and **@section .. @show** are used to be optionally overwritten whenever you extend the blade template. Everything you can do with **@yield** can also be done with **@section .. @show** but not the other way around. Here is what they do:

**@yield('main')**

- Can be replaced by **@section('main') .. @endsection**
- Can be provided with a default string but no HTML! The default string will be shown in the sub-blade-template when no **@section('main') .. @endsection** is provided.

**@section('main') .. @show**

- Can be replaced by **@section('main') .. @endsection**
- Can be provided with a default HTML code. The default HTML code will be shown in the sub-blade-template when no **@section('main')** is provided.
- Can be replaced by **@section('main')@parent .. @endsection** and additionally shows the default HTML code.

Here some examples:`test.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a test</h1>

    @yield('mainA')
    @yield('mainB', 'This is the alternative 1')
    @yield('mainC', '<p>This is the alternative 2</p>')
    @yield('mainD', 'This is the alternative 3')

    @section('testA')
    @show

    @section('testB')
      This is the alternative 4
    @show

    @section('testC')
      <p>This is the alternative 5</p>
    @show

    @section('testD')
      <p>This is the alternative 6</p>
    @show


  </body>
</html>
```

here is another file called `testA.blade.php` which extends the other bladed file:

```
@extends('test')

@section('mainD')
  <div>
    <p>First replacement!</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
@endsection

@section('testC')
  <div>
    <p>Second replacement!</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
@endsection

@section('testD')
  @parent
  <div>
    <p>Additional content</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
@endsection
```

And that is the outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**The shortest answer:**

Use `@yield` in master if you want to overwrite child data on master layout completely.

Use `@section` in master if you want to use master and child data together on child with `@parent` (Or overwrite child data on master layout like `@yield`)

Answer (score 5):

Basically `yield('content')` is a marker. For example, in the tag if you put a `yield('content')`, your saying this section has the name of content and by the way, you can name inside of the parenthesis anything you want. it doesn't have to be content. it can be yield('inside'). or anything you want.

And then in the child page where you want to import html from your layout page, you just say section`('name of the section')`.
for example, if you have marked your header in your layout page as yield`('my_head_band')` <-- or anything else you want, then in your child page you just say `@section('my_head_band')`.

This would import the header from the layout page into your child page. vice versa with your body section which in this case was named as content.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on something small,  `@yield` basically defines a section to be injected by `overwriting` the data and it also works if our view `@extends` the parent view.

Now when we `overwrite`, we replace an implementation completely with a new implementation, like a company can decide to change/overwrite its entire technology if they realize something went wrong.

It should not be confused with `override`

Answer (score 0):

@yield having default value in second parameter and section doesn't have in master if you want to overwrite child data on master layout completely then you will use @yield.

Use @section in master if you want to use master and child data together on child with @parent (Or overwrite child data on master layout like @yield)

Example

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show
 
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
@extends('layouts.master')
 
@section('title', 'Page Title')
 
@section('sidebar')
    @@parent
 
    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@stop
 
@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@stop
```