# Difference between @yield and @include Laravel Blade Templating importing CSS

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-blade

What is the main difference between these two keywords in blade, I found that they do same thing, but... The syntax is different, but whats the main difference?
I am using @yield, and @include, but didn't figure out, which is better to use?

I want to extend my CSS styles, I want to load css styles when needed, for example i want to separate styles and options to navbar and separate css styles to my footer defined in navbar.css, footer.css, i want to include in my main.blade.php, but footer isn't allways visible?

How to solve this? Do I think wrong, and its better to put all css to one file?
What about performance?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title> Authentication system</title>
    {{--custom css--}}
    @yield('css')
    {{HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    {{HTML::style('css/navbar.css')}}
</head>
<body>
@if(Session::has('global'))
    <p>{{Session::get('global')}}</p>
@endif
@include('layout.navigation')
@yield('content')
@yield('layout.footer')
```

and footer

```
@extends('layout.main')
@section('css')
    @parent
    {{HTML::style('css/footer.css')}}
@endsection
@section('footer')
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
@endsection
```

My code doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel - Difference between @yield and @section?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070456/laravel-difference-between-yield-and-section)

Comment: Maybe, but I edited for more specific information.

Comment: You'll need to include some code, if you want specific answers.

Comment: I use include for my navbar, but I load CSS in my main.blade.php. But i want to load CSS in footer.blade.php as extension of existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@yield('layout.footer')
```

write

```
@include('layout.footer')
```

This should solve your problem.